# Listbox scrolling insanely laggy with mouse wheel but not scrollbar?

Tags: c#, powershell, scroll, listbox

I'm building a GUI with PowerShell Studio but this is the same type of listbox you would do in C# with forms.

I have a simple listbox with around 70 items in it. 
If I click and move the SCROLLBAR, it's really smooth and there is no delay whatsover.
If I scroll with the MOUSEWHEEL, it's incredibly choppy and delayed, slow.

Why is that and how can it be fixed?

Check this recording to see it in action using the simplest example:

[image: scrolling by scrollbar and mouse wheel (animated)]

In the example I scroll the mouse wheel fast so it should go to the top quickly but it "lags" all the way in a very delayed fashion.

In notepad for example, it's instant.

Comment: I would suspect this is an issue with your mouse settings or driver rather than your code.

Comment: Good idea, i tried with 3 different mice, two standard lenovo enterprise models (USB) and one bluetooth, all of them have the same behaviour.